# numpy.matrix manipulations

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I have a question about numpy.matrix class. How can I perform such basic manipulations with matrices as adding, deleting and replacing rows and columns?

p.s. I apologize for the lame question..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly fine question! Try examining this code:

```
import scipy
X = scipy.rand(3,3)
Y = scipy.rand(3,3)
print X+Y
print scipy.delete(X, 1, 0)
print scipy.delete(X, 1, 1)
X[1,:] = [1,2,3]
print X
```

For more, see the numpy/scipy docs here: [NumPy/SciPy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/)

If you are fluent in Matlab, this page is useful: [NumPy for Matlab Users](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html)

Comment: Note that `X[1] = …` is faster than `X[1,:]` (because no interpretation of the slice is necessary, I would guess).